# Selenium Colab of Google

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-colaboratory

I got this in Colab. I did the installation:

```
# !pip install selenium
# !apt-get update # to update ubuntu to correctly run apt install
# !apt install chromium-chromedriver
# !cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
wd.get("https://ca.yahoo.com")
```

And I got the error below :

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:12: DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
  if sys.path[0] == '':
```

So I changed the code by removing the **chrome** from **chrome_options**:

```
# !pip install selenium
# !apt-get update # to update ubuntu to correctly run apt install
# !apt install chromium-chromedriver
# !cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)
wd.get("https://ca.yahoo.com")
```

Then when I run it again, then I got nothing. I expected a browser will be fired up and load Yahoo. But ... nothing..

Please help. Thank you so much in advance.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You are trying just changing the variable name. that's not the issue!
You should use different import.
Your code should be like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options #This is what you should add!
options = Options()
options.headless = True
wd = webdriver.Chrome(CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, options=options)
wd.get("https://ca.yahoo.com")
```

Pay attention that inside the `webdriver.Chrome(CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, options=options)` the first parameter is a path to chromedriver executable, not just a string "chromedriver"

Comment: thank you very much Prophet for your reply. The CHROMEDRIVER_PATH is for the local executable file. I want to run my code on Colab Google, so I can run it anywhere. 

Is the "wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)" OK ?

Comment: Again, here I see you just using a `'chromedriver'` string while it should be a path to where you have a chromdriver.exe on you PC. If you don't understan - just run what you have and you will see the error I'm talking about

Comment: thanks Prophet. Can I put the executable chromedriver on cloud (i.e: Google drive)  , get the link, put it in the CHROMEDRIVER_PATH's place, so I can run the program from any PC which is my goal ?

Comment: I didn't try this ever.

Comment: thank you so much Prophet. If you haven't tried it; I guess half of the planet haven't tried it. LOL. Really appreciate your time and wisdom.